# Как убрать междустрочный интервал в консоли C#?

Tags: c#, консоль

Как убрать междустрочный интервал в консоли C#?

Comment: Например, сменить шрифт

Comment: Да , помогло, спасибо. 
А через код поменять можно? В Console никакого свойства и метода не обнаружил?

Comment: По идее можно через WinAPI. Сейчас поищу...

Comment: Готово, пробуйте!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё можно через WinAPI!

Вот такая программа:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COORD
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;
    public COORD(short X, short Y) { this.X = X; this.Y = Y; }
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public class CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
{
    public CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX()
    {
        cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX>();
    }

    public int cbSize;
    public int nFont;
    public COORD dwFontSize;
    public int FontFamily;
    public int FontWeight;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
    public string FaceName;
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    extern static bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
        bool bMaximumWindow,
        [In, Out] CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX lpConsoleCurrentFont);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
       IntPtr ConsoleOutput,
       bool MaximumWindow,
       CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX ConsoleCurrentFontEx
       );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int dwType);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am console output");
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        IntPtr handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX fi = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
        var result = GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(handle, false, fi);
        if (!result)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Now font is " + fi.FaceName + " setting to Lucida Console");
        fi.FaceName = "Lucida Console";
        result = SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(handle, false, fi);
        if (!result)
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am console output with new font");
    }
}
```

выдаёт результат:

[image: прикольно, да?]

Comment: Спасибо! все работает!

Comment: @MikhailZnak: Пожалуйста!