# Как увеличить буквы в выводе консольного приложения?

Tags: c#

Как увеличить буквы в выводе консольного приложения?

Comment: Лучше использовать нормальное GUI окно, а не пытаться сделать странное в консоли.

Comment: Для ответа мало, так что оставлю тут. Поменять можно только шрифт полностью, например через системные настройки, вывести в консоль разные строки разными шрифтами невозможно.

Comment: если шрифт поменять не можете, можно аналогом FIGlet воспользоваться, [вот пример на Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9632995/4279)

Comment: Вот так можно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605066/10105

Answer (score 9):

```
888888b.    .d88888b. 88888888888      88888888888     d8888 888    d8P  
888  "88b  d88P" "Y88b    888              888        d88888 888   d8P   
888  .88P  888     888    888              888       d88P888 888  d8P    
8888888K.  888     888    888              888      d88P 888 888d88K     
888  "Y88b 888     888    888              888     d88P  888 8888888b    
888    888 888     888    888              888    d88P   888 888  Y88b   
888   d88P Y88b. .d88P    888              888   d8888888888 888   Y88b  
8888888P"   "Y88888P"     888              888  d88P     888 888    Y88b
```

Ответ вроде бы шуточный, но если вам нужно вывести логотип или заголовок, вполне работоспособный вариант. Автоматический конвертер: http://patorjk.com/software/taag или погуглите "text to ascii art".

Вот еще библиотека, которая выводит текст в виде ASCII art разными цветами: http://colorfulconsole.com/ Есть [Nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Colorful.Console).

Comment: Отличное, кстати решение, о котором я не подумал.

Answer (score 2):

Шрифт консоли определяется настройками самой консоли. Теоретически можно полезть в реестр из своего приложения и заменить там шрифт. Но пользователи вашей программы за это вам спасибо не скажут, так как скорее всего огребут проблем в других (зачастую весьма неожиданных) местах. Поэтому никак.

З.Ы. Для доступа к реестру, вашему приложению, понадобятся довольно широкие права, не факт, пользователь захочет и главное сможет их выделить в своей ОС.

Comment: В винде настройки есть как общепользовательские, так и специфические для приложения. Теоретически их как-то менять можно. Хранятся они тоже в реестре, вроде.

Comment: @Squidward, сомневаюсь, что именно для настройки консоли там есть такое свойство, скорее уже настройки запуска программы надо использовать (ярлык?). Но если вы знаете ответ, то буду за него благодарен, самому приходилось сталкиваться, но именно по настройки консоли материалов в сети мало.

Comment: Ярлыки LNK не умеют хранить подобную информацию, насколько мне известно. Детальные настройки консоли хранились в PIF, например. / Поковырялся в реестре, найденное запостил в своём ответе.

Answer (score 2):

У меня в реестре виднеются ключи вроде `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe` следующего содержимого:

```bash
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe]
"ColorTable05"=dword:00562401
"ColorTable06"=dword:00f0edee
"FaceName"="Lucida Console"
"FontFamily"=dword:00000036
"FontWeight"=dword:00000190
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f3
"QuickEdit"=dword:00000001
"ScreenBufferSize"=dword:0bb80078
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000056
"WindowSize"=dword:00320078
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что специфические для консольных приложений настройки хранятся здесь, причём слеши в пути заменяются на символ подчёркивания. Там же есть ключ "Git Bash", то есть поддерживаются не только пути, но и заголовки (?) окон. Можно также попробовать имена файлов без полного пути.

Короче, попробуйте средствами, встроенными в ось, настроить отображение консоли в вашем приложении (меню открывается по правому клику на заголовке окна), и посмотрите, каким образом эти настройки сохраняются. Настройки, скорее всего, окажутся в районе `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`.

Comment: @rdorn *не, настройки встроенной консоли едины для всех программ* — Почему же тогда у меня настройки сохраняются для конкретных программ? Вот сейчас пошёл запустил свою программу, изменил настройки, появился ключ `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\D:_Docs_Projects_CsConsoleFormat_bin_Debug_Alba.CsConsoleFormat.ConsoleTest.exe`.

Comment: хм... нашел где это, забавно, надо будет поиграться на досуге. Как то я пропустил этот момент. Предыдущий комментарий пожалуй удалю, чтобы не сбивал с толку других. Там действительно полная кастомизация под каждое приложение по необходимости, любые параметры, доступные в основной ветке могут быть перекрыты параметрами приложения. Жаль только, что это исключительно пользовательские настройки, хотя это уже не мало, и не требует повышенных привилегий у пользователя для сохранения и изменения этих настроек.

Comment: Неплохо бы выяснить, для каких версий Windows это работает. Консоль стала сильно более функциональной в Win10

Comment: @Андрей Вроде, эти настройки там всегда были, в десятке только новые опции добавили. Если бы принимали ставки на то, когда эта функция была добавлена, я бы поставил на 2000 или XP — с приходом cmd на замену встроенного DOS. Вот формат настроек мог измениться, я что-то не припоминаю длинных путей в этом ключе раньше...

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы это сделать поставьте перед кавычками @ и всё выполнится

> Пример:

[image: Пример]

Вставляется кривовато, но вывод работает корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вывелись непонятные символы, то просто растяните консоль